# Error in admin: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Tags: django, model, typeerror, admin

The admin returns this error when trying to add an instance to one of my models. The model itself has a correct **str**() method and contains no instances yet. Also tried replacing the **str**() method with a static method or removing it altogether. No luck.

The error seems to point towards something going wrong in the history part of the admin. Stacktrace points to line 33.

```
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/snirp/juis/snirpdrive/glotto/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html, error at line 33
__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
23  {% endblock %}
24  {% endif %}
25  
26  {% block content %}<div id="content-main">
27  {% block object-tools %}
28  {% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
29    <ul class="object-tools">
30      {% block object-tools-items %}
31      <li>
32          {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}
33          <a href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a>
34      </li>
35      {% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="{{ absolute_url }}" class="viewsitelink">{% trans "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif %}
36      {% endblock %}
37    </ul>
38  {% endif %}{% endif %}
39  {% endblock %}
40  <form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.model_name }}_form" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}{% block form_top %}{% endblock %}
41  <div>
42  {% if is_popup %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ is_popup_var }}" value="1" />{% endif %}
43  {% if to_field %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ to_field_var }}" value="{{ to_field }}" />{% endif %}
```

These are the relevant parts of my `models.py` and `admin.py`

```
class UserContent(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_creator')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_updater')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Linetrans(UserContent):
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line)
    translation = models.ForeignKey(Translation)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['line']
```

and

```
admin.site.register(Linetrans)
```

Other model classes are very similar and do not return an error. The error also occurs when the Linetrans is added as an inline to another admin class.

edit / update: I commented out all other str() methods in my model and sure enough the error seems to go away. Now trying to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Turns out that there was an unexpected empty CharField in a related model. Leaving this an an answer, because it might help others.

**Troubleshoot the issue** by systematically commenting out the `__str__()` methods of your models until you find the offending model. Work from there to identify the offending record(s).

Comment: I had a __str__ method that returned `self.title` instead of `self.title or ''`.

Comment: I just spent an hour on irc just to get to Seth's solution. +1 You should still try to find the offending object, I think.

Comment: That was so helpful. Didn't know where the error was, saw this answer and changed ```self.name to self.name or ' '``` and totally worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Had a similar problem--modified a model with `on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, null=True`, and that broke the `__str__` for the admin interface. Used @seth method: `return self.NAME or ''` and solved the mystery.

Comment: I had `__str__` return `self.data` (JSON information) instead of `str(self.data)`

Comment: why is adding self.name or '' a solution? @Seth

Comment: @ProsyArceno if `self.name` is `None`, then you'll be returning a non-string type (None) from the `__str__` method, which results in the error. This happens to most of us because we don't _think_ `self.name` (or whatever) can be `None`, but then life happens.

Comment: I had __str__ function in a ForeignField, that was supposed to return string but was still giving error. I just convert the return value to str and it worked!

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar issue. The problem was that the primary key for one row was null ( I dont know how that happened). I couldnt delete the row because of cascade issues. so I had to change the **str** mmethod to somthing like this.

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.customerName==None:
        return "ERROR-CUSTOMER NAME IS NULL"
    return self.customerName
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a test row with NULL in one of the columns which was being referenced elsewhere. Deleting the test row fixed the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Check out the class that you have referred to in

```
        models.ForeignKey
```

The problem lies in the

```
        __str__()
```

method of one of those classes.
Then, add

```
                             or ''
```

in the return statement of that class like this.

```
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title or ''
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. I completely forgot this. My model list was showing perfectly but whenever I try to update the data it shows the __str__ error.

Answer (score 6):

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.topic)
```

Use str to make it type string.
Then it's not not-string type.

Answer (score 3):

For this error you can use two solutions

**first solution**: you can comment it out below code

```
 def __str__(self):
    return self.id
```

to

```
 #def __str__(self):
 #  return self.id
```

**secound solution**: you can return the string from the object

```
 def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

that's works for me:

```
    def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.category}"
```

Just use "f" string

Answer (score 1):

You can also delete the instances in the model causing this problem from the django shell `python manage.py shell` . This helps when you are dealing with a model with lots of related models like mine.

> Typically this problem is caused by altering model fields and
>   migrating, such that the instances are incompatible with each other
>   and related fields

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use `__str__()` to return the value of a `ForeignKey` or a `OneToOneField` this would return error

Example:

```
def __str__():
    return self.user  # where user is a key to other model class
```

It should be:

```
def __str__():
    return self.user.__str__() 
    # Or basically any other way that would explicitly unbox the value inside the related model class.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the same issue and its origin was that: for the field used in the `__str__` functions, has null values saved in the data base.

So I can solve the issue doing somethings like this:

```
update table
set field_for_STR_use = 'any value'
where field_for_STR_use is null or field_for_STR_use = ''
```

after that, I only refreshed my view and the problem had disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

There was one of the foreign reference which was returning non string field. I changed it to string field or you can change to str(foreign-key-return-element)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True) # name of the article
parent = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='category_parent_item', default=None, null=True) # Store child items
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # Creation date
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # Updation Date
user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),

on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='category_update_user', default=None, null=True) #User who updated the Article

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name ----------> this was an integer field initially in foreign reference
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a different model that was called by another one that had the default snippet from VSCode as:

```
def __str__(self):
    return
```

This was causing the error, even when it was showing in the log another place.

Answer (score 0):

Toto_tico is right, although the above error can also occur when you fail to return a str property of your django model within the **str**(self) method:

```
Class model and(models.Model):
    Class Meta:
       verbose_name = "something"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    #Error instance:
    def __str__(self):
       self.title

    #Right way
    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

So it is highly advised to return the str property within the

> def **str**(self)

method to avoid errors in the Django admin panel when trying to make changes to a particular data within a model table:

```
    def __str__(self):
       return self.property
```

I hope this will help someone.