# How to fix Django admin page error related to `__str__`

Tags: django, django-admin

Had a `None type` error on the admin page because of an empty field (`null=True`) in the db table. Followed of of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230395/5965865) with `return self.author or '' +  self.post_title[:40]` and fixed the error.

Now how do I get both the author and title of post appear in the admin page. The previous (broken) code: `return self.author + ', ' + self.post_title[:40]`, but once I add `or ''`, the part following `+` stops working.

Comment: If you use `return self.author or '' +  self.post_title[:40]`, it is interpreted as `return (self.author) or ('' +  self.post_title[:40])`

Comment: Actually it only returns `self.author`. How do I have it return both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `return self.author or '' +  self.post_title[:40]`, it is interpreted as

```
return (self.author) or ('' +  self.post_title[:40])
```

which will thus return the `self.author`, or in case that author is `None` (or any other value with truthiness `False`) the empty string concatenated with `self.post_title[:40]`.

You can implement this logic with:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.author or ""}, {self.post_title[:40]}'
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks! But curious though: This code is in `models.py`. Before seeing your response, I started tinkering w `admin.py`--the changes there didn't seem affect the admin page. Where should this block of code go?

Comment: @YCode: in the `models.py`.

Comment: When the `__str__` is defined in models.py, the code in admin.py (`def __str__(self):
    return self.title`) seems repetitive. I removed it with no obvious ill consequence. Now I realized there is a lot of duplication btw my admin.py and models.py. Is it a matter of preference or is there a best practice which one to use?

Comment: @YCode: no, you should *not* define a `__str__` in `admin.py`. The `ModelAdmin` itself does *not* determine how a model object is formatted, this is what the model class does, so you can remove the `__str__` over there.

Comment: Learned and understood a huge amount from your responses! Much appreciated!